# Is using Rpart with unbalanced data a good idea?

Tags: r, unbalanced-classes, accuracy, rpart

I have a rather unbalanced data set and want to use rpart to build a classification tree. After building the full tree, I prune it back using the 1-SE rule. On average, only 1-2 splits are suggested. I was wondering, as far as I understood, cp is basically picked to maximise accuracy. However, this is suboptimal since accuracy is not a good performance measure for unbalanced data sets. My initial plan was basically to adjust the classification threshold eventually and pick the one which maximises for example the F1-score. But this is somehow inconsistent in my view. Running a tree first and pick cp so that accuracy is maximised although I know that cannot be the ultimate goal here. I would really appreciate some help here? I'm a little bit stuck here. Thank you!

Comment: What about using svm with different class weights? I am having a similar issue where only 0.06% for my data are in class 1. The method you proposed would make sense if you use cross-validation/bootstrapping to optimize the cutoff.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I am using cross-validation. What do you mean exactly by optimising the cutoff? But the question remains, rpart is trained to optimise accuracy even though this is not optimal here. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I am actually not too sure about that too .. but what I was thinking is maybe manually write a function in `r` to get the cp cutoff that maximizes F1-score.

Comment: Interesting thought - let me please know when you find a solution. My current approach is to use a loss matrix to weight misclassifications differently. This gives me pretty high balanced accuracy. However, I'm not sure that's the way to go...

Comment: I am surprised to see that approach inproved accuracy, normally when you increase the loss portion for one(e.g. False Positive), it will also the occurrence of the other (False Negative).

Comment: Yeah - that's the common problem. However, it's a special case I guess since rpart worked really bad for me (it only split once) there was no leeway for me to adjust for example the cutoff to get better results. What I mean is when I plotted the ROC curve, obviously I had one kink and adjusting the cutoff didn't change anything. In using a loss matrix however, I actually do get a tree (3-4 splits) using the 1-SE rule.

Comment: I fit a random forest with my data with loss matrix ` loss=matrix(c(0,2,1,0))`, and the results are not bad. I am going to try the SMOTE oversampling method and see if it improves. How's yours going?\